# Decrement font-size on condition, why is my recursive function not working?

Tags: javascript, css, recursion, responsive-design, font-size

I have a `<p>` element inside a parent `<div>` container. The parent container is sized with `width` and `height` as a % of the viewport. Upon window-resize, I want to decrement the font-size of `<p>` until the height of the `<p>` element is less than 40% of the viewport height, which means the text will fit nicely into the parent container.

What's wrong with my function below?

The error I am getting is 'maximum call stack size exceeded'. I know that must be because the base case is not evaluating to true. However I don't understand why not.

**I've run these various tests to try to debug without success:**

- Does adjusting font-size through my fontSize variable work: yes
- Does adjusting font-size impact height of `<p>` element: yes
- Can I adjust font-size multiple times and see decreased `<p>` element size in the console: yes

**The function:**

```
<script>
    const pElement = document.getElementById('actualAboutTxt');
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(pElement, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
    var fontSize = parseFloat(style);

    function decrementFont () {
        if(pElement.scrollHeight <= (window.innerHeight * 0.4)) {
            // do nothing
        } else {
            pElement.style.fontSize = (fontSize - 1) + "px";
            decrementFont();
        };
    };

    addEventListener("load", () => {
        decrementFont();
    });

    addEventListener("resize", () => {
        decrementFont();
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT 1: Update with the HTML and CSS (anonymised some urls):**

```
<section id="mainSection">
        <div class="backBtnDiv">
            <button id="backToFilter" onclick="window.location.href='<link to my url>';">&#8634 back to filter</button>
        </div> 
        <video id="background-video" autoplay loop muted poster="<link to my poster img>">
            <source src="<link to my video>">
        </video>
        <div id="aboutText">
            <h1>Practice makes perfect</h1>
            <p id="actualAboutTxt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ultrices enim id leo commodo, ac commodo dolor laoreet. Quisque eget facilisis dui. Ut sit amet dui ultrices, ultrices eros ut, auctor purus. Nulla bibendum velit in rhoncus rutrum.<br><br>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ultrices enim id leo commodo, ac commodo dolor laoreet. Quisque eget facilisis dui. Ut sit amet dui ultrices, ultrices eros ut, auctor purus. Nulla bibendum velit in rhoncus rutrum.<br><br>  
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ultrices enim id leo commodo, ac commodo dolor laoreet. Quisque eget facilisis dui. Ut sit amet dui ultrices, ultrices eros ut, auctor purus. Nulla bibendum velit in rhoncus rutrum.</p>
            <button id="firstBtn" onclick="window.location.href='<link to myurl';">Start practicing</button>
        </div>
</section>

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Archivo', arial; 
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

#mainSection {
    position : relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 90vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.backBtnDiv {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#backToFilter {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
}

#backToFilter:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#aboutText {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    height: 60%;
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}

#actualAboutTxt {
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#firstBtn {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 7.5vh;
    width: 75%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: transparent;
    background-color: rgb(77, 5, 232);
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#firstBtn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #9bc969;
}

#background-video {
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
#aboutText {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2: A solution that kind of works:**

Use a double recursive function to keep the `<p>` element between two `vh` values. Decrement font if the element is too high, increment font if the element is not heigh enough.

Code:

```
<script>
    const pElement = document.getElementById('actualAboutTxt');
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(pElement, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
    var fontSize = parseFloat(style);

    function decrementFont () {
        if(pElement.scrollHeight > (window.innerHeight * 0.30) && pElement.scrollHeight < (window.innerHeight * 0.42)) {
            return;
        } else if (pElement.scrollHeight > (window.innerHeight * 0.42)) {
            pElement.style.fontSize = (--fontSize) + "px";
            decrementFont();
        } else if (pElement.scrollHeight < (window.innerHeight * 0.35)) {
            pElement.style.fontSize = (++fontSize) + "px";
            decrementFont();
        };
    };

    addEventListener("load", () => {
        decrementFont();
    });

    addEventListener("resize", () => {
        decrementFont();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, can you share the CSS and maybe HTML too? I am pretty sure that we do not need JS for what you want to achieve :)

Comment: This loops forever because the `fontSize` variable is never updated. You only set it once at the top of your script.

Try `pElement.style.fontSize = (--fontSize) + "px";`

(But Dylan is right - you can probably do this without JS)

Comment: @DylanBarquilla Updated with my HTML and CSS. It's quite a bit... I have tried working with calc() and making a media query for just about every screen-size scenario I can think of. The best I got was just getting the text very small, so that the div would have lots of space left in it, but my intention/desire is to shrink the text only so that it fits exactly.

Comment: @AlfieWoodland Your solution worked! However now I am stuck with a text that upon screen resize for a second time, is very small. Because the text doesn't again expand when the div gets bigger. Perhaps that makes no difference as likely users will only open the site once and not continuously resize the screen. Thanks a bunch though! Good to know that was it. Was crushing my brain over this :p

Comment: @bassiee I'm glad Alfie gave you the solution. To be honest I don't really know how to use the following, but I know the "clamp()" CSS method is the modern way to have responsive font-size. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/css/clamp to begin with)

Comment: @DylanBarquilla hey thanks, didn't know about that one. Will definitely keep it in mind.

Comment: You are using recursion when regular loops would do. Odd choice.

Comment: @LeeTaylor That wasn't a conscious choice. As I am quite new to this, a recursion was all I could think of. Would love to hear how you would use a regular loop, if you are up for sharing.

Comment: @bassiee See my answer. Although I'm posting my code as an answer, this is only to demonstrate what you asked for.

Comment: "the text doesn't again expand when the div gets bigger."  That's because you don't ask it to.  If you started it off at a really large value on every resize and then performed the remainder of the algorithm, it should work... although you might want to debounce to resize events.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet is an example of non-recursive solution as asked for by the OP. There is no HTML (at present), so it will not work.

Additionally, the code may not ever satisfy the condition, so the loop may run forever.

Using recursion for an non-recursive task is not ideal. You are creating an unnecessary stack when you use recursion here.

```js
const pElement = document.getElementById('actualAboutTxt');
const style = window.getComputedStyle(pElement, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
var fontSize = parseFloat(style);

function decrementFont() 
{
  let fontOK = false;
  do
  {
    if (pElement.scrollHeight > (window.innerHeight * 0.30) && pElement.scrollHeight < (window.innerHeight * 0.42)) 
    {
      fontOK = true;
    } 
    else if (pElement.scrollHeight > (window.innerHeight * 0.42)) 
    {
      pElement.style.fontSize = (--fontSize) + "px";
    } 
    else if (pElement.scrollHeight < (window.innerHeight * 0.35)) 
    {
      pElement.style.fontSize = (++fontSize) + "px";
    }
  }
  while(!fontOK);
}

addEventListener("load", () => {
  decrementFont();
});

addEventListener("resize", () => {
  decrementFont();
});
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for sharing. Had not thought to use a loop like that.

Comment: @bassiee Far easier to see what's going on and recursiveness is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand here is a problem.

```
if(pElement.scrollHeight <= (window.innerHeight * 0.4)) {
            // do nothing
        }
```

so if height will be less or equal to whatever you want then this recursion should end yes? this is a point of recursion and if you will not write a break; it will continue so instead of writing // do nothing comment you should write a break; try this end and see if it works.

Comment: I think the "break" keyword is useful in loops. Here, if the condition is reached (it does not seem to be the case here), you want a "return" statement, or nothing and the function will end at the end of the function, without calling another time the recursive function.

Comment: I had that before but it doesn't work unfortunately. Alfie in a comment above solved it -- even though the end result is still not ideal, but that's because apparently my solution is not the best.